# Django template if statement doesn't return what I expected

Tags: python, django

I want to allow users to edit their own comments. I tried to compare comment.nick as well as to request.user.username and to request.user.get_username. For example comment.nick return 'author' and request.user.username will return 'author', but Edit won't be visible.

```
{% if request.user.username == comment.nick %}
    <a href="{% url 'edit_comment' comment.id %}">Edit</a>
{% endif %}


# models.py
class Commentary(models.Model):
    nick = models.ForeignKey('Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=20)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: But `comment.nick` is an instance of Profile. It will never be equal to the username, which is a string. Did you mean `if request.user == comment.nick.user`?

Comment: Thank you so much. The answer is `{% if request.user == comment.nick.user %}`. I thought that 'if' compare two strings, but 'if' compare objects? Am I right?

Comment: It's nothing to do with `if`, it's that as I said nick is a Profile instance, not a string.